# Why solidify modifier extrude extra edges

Tags: modifiers

With the reference [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p35sEHj6ndg&list=PLJeCLX8zzeAiWv-xaR72v8DUFRpXoJ5GI) Im making the sofa. I have made the handles and when im trying to add the solidify modifier. I have add the images 1st image is the normal without solidify and 2nd and 3rd image with red mark are the images after solidify is added.  I have align the vertex also. Yet to not get the better result. The handle not solidify outer side like offset as seen in the video. Whats wrong with my basic mode.[image]

[image]
enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You model as duplicate geometry and overlapping faces at the bottom.

Either:

- Enter edit mode and press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*. You may have to increase the *Threshold* value in the tool shelf, or
- Manually delete the duplicate faces at the bottom of the mesh, then close the gaps.

Comment: i have check there are no doubles and normal also in correct direction outside

Comment: I have checked and *there are* doubles

Answer (score 0):

Duarte is right, [image]

its a problem with the mesh.